# SQL join 2 queries in one from same table

Tags: sql

I have a table like that

IVA

```
id - taxa - name   - date
1  - 0.18 - normal - 1/1/2014
2  - 0    - none   - 1/1/2014 
3  - 0.23 - max    - 1/1/2013
4  - 0.16 - normal - 1/1/2015
...
```

I have an `IVA.id` from a product and I want to know in current date what is the taxa.

So I have to query this table twice:

```
Select name 
from IVA 
where id = 1; (return me normal)

Select taxa 
from IVA 
where name = 'normal' 
  and date <= '12/12/2015';
```

Can I join these two queries into only one?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
Select taxa 
from IVA 
where name in (Select a.name from IVA a where a.id = 1) 
and date<='12/12/2015';
```

Comment: Thanks, if i only want the closest data how do i do?

Comment: Got it! Select top 1 taxa 
from IVA 
where name in (Select a.name from IVA a where a.id = 1) 
and date<='12/12/2015' order by date desc;

Comment: That's  great you did it by yourself. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database engine you're using, but you may want to look up the UNION keyword for your database.

Comment: Not sure why `UNION` would be useful here.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question then... Considering the queries above are pulling from two distinctly different rows of the database (it appeared that ID was an incrementing int), are pulling different columns, and the original poster hasn't provided a sample of what they want their output to look like... I thought they wanted both of the results of the two queries in one result, not a single query that returned a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use subqueries as below :

```
Select taxa 
from IVA 
where name=(select top 1 name from IVA where id = 1)
and date<='12/12/2015';
```

I have assumed that you might get different names in case there are duplicate IDs, hence Top 1.
In case you want to use all the names used IN clause as :

```
Select taxa 
from IVA 
where name IN (select name from IVA where id = 1)
and date<='12/12/2015';
```

PS : Top 1 may not work in all scenarios. It's engine specific.

Comment: Not every DBMS is going to have `TOP`

Comment: thnx for pointing that out :), I'll mention that in my answer.

Comment: An ID should be unique for a table, so you should always get 1 or 0 rows for a specified ID. You can use = without any TOP or LIMIT clause hence.

Comment: Ideally it should be unique, I just went extra bit cautious, have seen people using foreign keys with the name id, but thnx for the suggestion, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
SELECT i1.name, i1.taxa
  FROM iva i1, iva i2
 WHERE i1.date <= '12/12/2015'
   AND i1.name = i2.name
   AND i2.id = 1
```

You don't specify a DBMS in your question so I'm not entirely certain that the above date format will work.

Comment: You may want to consider using the current ANSI standard as well.